# Program crashes when getting canvas height or width

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, graph

So I am just trying to draw a x and y axis on a canvas in a WPF window. I had the canvas in my main window, and my draw method worked, however I tried to put this canvas in a new window and my program crashed. (When in a new window) The program crashes when it reaches a call to gCanvas.Height or gCanvas.Width, but if I change these to gCanvas.ActualHeight and gCanvas.ActualWidth the program runs, but it does not draw the x and y axis. Does anyone know why the method works when the canvas is in my main window but not in my new window, here is the code :

```
private void draw()
    {

        Line xAxis = new Line();
        Line yAxis = new Line();


        xAxis.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightSteelBlue;
        xAxis.X1 = 0;
        xAxis.X2 = gCanvas.Width;
        xAxis.Y1 = (gCanvas.Height / 2);
        xAxis.Y2 = (gCanvas.Height / 2);
        xAxis.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        xAxis.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        xAxis.StrokeThickness = 2;


        gCanvas.Children.Add(xAxis);


        yAxis.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightSteelBlue;
        yAxis.X1 = (gCanvas.Width / 2);
        yAxis.X2 = (gCanvas.Width / 2);
        yAxis.Y1 = 0;
        yAxis.Y2 = gCanvas.Height;
        yAxis.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        yAxis.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        yAxis.StrokeThickness = 2;


        gCanvas.Children.Add(yAxis);


    }
```

Here is the XAML for the 2nd window

```
<Window x:Class="Control.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window1" Height="362" Width="412">
<Grid>
    <Canvas Name="gCanvas" Margin="5" Background="White"/>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

and i call my draw function like this

```
public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (this.IsLoaded)
            draw(); 

    }
```

Comment: How are you adding it to the new window? Code please

Comment: It is highly recommendable that you define the UI in XAML as opposed to creating it procedurally in C# code. You won't find any of these problems what way.

Comment: Can you show the XAML for the first window too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, your question is

> *Does anyone know why the method works when the canvas is in my main window but not in my new window?*

Well, no. *You* are the only person that can *know* that. However, from your problem description, I can tell that your `gCanvas` control has not been rendered at the time that you have called your `draw` method. I can tell this because your `Exception` was thrown at the `gCanvas.Width` call, so that must have had a value of `Nan`, or *Not a Number*.

The `ActualWidth` property will not return that value, so that is why that worked. As the shape was not drawn, I could therefore assume that the `ActualWidth` property returned `0`. So if this is the case, then that points to the fact that you *must* be calling the `draw` method too early and if you're doing it in the constructor, then that *is* too early. Instead, handle the [`FrameworkElement.Loaded` Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the `Window`:

```
public YourWindow()
{
    ...
    Loaded += YourWindow_Loaded;
}

private void YourWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    draw();
}
```